# How to install “wps-community / wps_i18n” from Github?

Tags: linux-mint, source, github

I'm new in Linux and trying to install WPS-Office from Github. I've already tried to install it from Snap and from Flatpak but neither works satisfactorily. One, there's correct punctuation (éâã etc) but there isn't a spell checker for pt-Br. On the other hand, there's a correct spell checker for pt-Br but its punctuation (éâã etc) doesn't work properly. I've also tried to install from the official website. Now, I'm trying this version from Github (https://github.com/wps-community/wps_i18n).

I need to know how to install it with step-by-step commands or any alternative that works fine.

System info: OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Cinnamon version: 4.4.8

Linux Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic

Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list

```
          Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 

          1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable

          Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-bionic.list 

          1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic main

          Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 

          1: deb http: //mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages tricia main upstream import backport

          2: deb http: //sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse

          3: deb http: //sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

          4: deb http: //sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

          5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

          6: deb http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
          Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oguzhaninan-stacer-bionic.list 

          1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu bionic main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded package should contain instructions. If not, perhaps the package's webpage gives hints. Or some comments or bug report helps.

Often it a script called `bootstrap` or some such has to run before configuring and building.